# Dismiss modal view and change tab in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am looking for a way to dismiss a modal view and switch to a specific tab on the tab bar.

I think I need to combine....

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
```

and

```
self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES;
```

Both work individually but not when combined.

Comment: Why not? What problem are you having? How did you call the 2 methods?

Comment: One method is that after you click a certain tab or so set selectedIndex to 3 then presenting view, thus after dismissing it will automatically brings u to the 3rd tab

Comment: At the moment I call both of those functions in an IBAction for a button. When the button is pressed it just dismisses the modal view, doesn't change the tab.

Comment: @DonPeters firstly may i ask what is your navigation logic as in TabBarController -> ViewController then back to TabBarController?

Comment: The TabBar links to a page of information which pops up in a modal view then there is an option to go back or another option to go to a different TabBar tab.

Comment: @DonPeters then after the user clicks the link, it calls for an action to bring user to the 3rd tab bar and then shows the new view controller, after dismissing this controller it will bring you back to the 3rd tab bar

Comment: Thats a good idea but most people wont want to always go back to the 3rd tab.

Comment: @DonPeters in reality most people when they navigate through the app if the 3rd bar brings u to a new view controller, it only make sense if the back button brings u back to the exact same bar unless the function being more like a home button instead?

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the tab bar's selected index upon the calling of viewDidDisappear or viewWillDisappear for the dismissed controller? This way, they won't be called together but will happen one after the other